# Acceptable practice to use 'group_by' stats in mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr

In the past, when I've needed to create a new variable in an R data frame that is partly based on a 'group_by' summary statistic, I've always used the following sequence:

(1) calculate 'group stats' from data in the base (ungrouped) data frame using group_by() and summarize()

(2) join the base data frame with the result of the previous step, then calculate the new variable value using mutate.

However, (after years of using dplyr!) I accidentally did the 'summarizing' in a mutate step and everything seemed to work. This is illustrated in Option #2 in the code snippet below. I'm assuming Option #2 is okay because I'm getting identical results using both options, and because I found similar examples searching the web today. However, I wasn't sure.

Is Option #2 acceptable practice, or is Option #1 preferred (and if so why)?

```
set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(year_ = c(rep(c(2019), 4), rep(c(2020), 4)),
             qtr_ = c(rep(c(1,2,3,4), 2)),
             foo = sample(seq(1:8)))

# Option 1: calc statistics then rejoin with input data
df_stats <- df %>%
  group_by(year_) %>%
  summarize(mean_foo = mean(foo))

df_with_stats <- left_join(df, df_stats) %>%
  mutate(dfoo = foo - mean_foo)

# Option 2: everything in one go
df_with_stats2 <- df %>%
  group_by(year_) %>%
  mutate(mean_foo = mean(foo),
         dfoo = foo - mean_foo)
```

```
df_with_stats
# A tibble: 8 x 5
  year_  qtr_   foo mean_foo  dfoo
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>    <dbl> <dbl>
1  2019     1     7        6     1
2  2019     2     8        6     2
3  2019     3     3        6    -3
4  2019     4     6        6     0
5  2020     1     2        3    -1
6  2020     2     4        3     1
7  2020     3     5        3     2
8  2020     4     1        3    -2
```

```
df_with_stats2
# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   year_ [2]
  year_  qtr_   foo mean_foo  dfoo
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>    <dbl> <dbl>
1  2019     1     7        6     1
2  2019     2     8        6     2
3  2019     3     3        6    -3
4  2019     4     6        6     0
5  2020     1     2        3    -1
6  2020     2     4        3     1
7  2020     3     5        3     2
8  2020     4     1        3    -2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 is fine, if you don't need the intermediate object anyway, and you don't even need to create `mean_foo` in your mutate statement:

```
df %>% group_by(year_) %>% mutate(dfoo=foo-mean(foo))
```

also, data.table

```
setDT(df)[,dfoo:=foo-mean(foo), by =year_]
```

Comment: #Langtang: Algebraically you are of course correct, but the separation is useful (especially to dplyr novices) to demonstrate how mutate can encompass more than one new object.

Comment: agree with that @WBarker.. You are right, readability counts for more than conciseness, in many instances. I did not mean to obfuscate.